# angular 4 @Input paramter changed inside a subscribe does not update the view

Tags: angular

I have got a select component and I parameter it like this:

```
<app-select-v2
  [formGroup]="model"
  [controlName]="'owner'"
  [options]="ownerOptions"
  [label]="'Select task\'s owner'"
  [width]="'100%'"
  [height]="'30rem'"
  [scrollFrom]="5"
></app-select-v2>
```

This is a custom select-option list what gets the ownerOptions array. The array looks like this:

```
ownerOptions:Option[] = [
    {name: 'name1', value: 'value1'},
    {name: 'name2', value: 'value2'}
    ...
];
```

At the start this is an empty array and I want to fill it with data. The setOwnerOptions() function what is suppose to do the fill. I call it in ngOnInit()

```
setOwnerOptions(){ 
    this._calendar.getActiveUsers().subscribe((names:string[]) => {
      for(var i:number = 0; i<names.length; i++){
        var _option = new Option();
        this._calendar.getUserFullName(names[i]).subscribe((fullname:string) =>{
          _option.name = fullname;
          _option.value = names[i];
          this.ownerOptions.push(_option);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

(I know this is not the best way to get the id(name) and full_names from the api. I will rewrite this part soon.) The getActiveUsers() and the getUserFullName(name:string) functions are working fine. I get the requested data from the api and the loop is pushing it to the ownerOptions array. But the point is the view does not update and outside of the subscribe the ownerOptions is still an empty array because angular doesn't notice the change.
Could someone help me with this please? I have sort of experience with this :/
(I tried to create a zone and run the script with changeRef but It worked the same for me.)

Thanks your answers and time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
_option.value = names[i];
```

At this point `i` equals `names.length - 1` for all subscriptions. It's indeed not the best piece of code, but it's hard to see what you actually want to achieve, so to fix your issue you can change it to this. By using a `forEach` loop you prevent this issue:

```
setOwnerOptions(){ 
  this._calendar.getActiveUsers().subscribe(names => {
    names.forEach(name => 
      this._calendar.getUserFullName(name).subscribe(fullname => {
        let option = new Option();
        option.name = fullname;
        option.value = name;
        this.ownerOptions.push(_option);
    })
  })
}
```

Not entirely sure, but I believe you can also just fix it by using the `let` keyword in the `for loop`, instead of `var`. Actually, you should -never- use the `var` keyword, unless you really know what you are doing, and even then you know not to use it

Answer (score 1):

Implement `OnChanges` in your child component :

```
export class SelectV2 implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  // ...
  ngOnChanges(change: SimpleChange) {
    console.log(change);
  }
}
```

this method will be triggered everytime an `Input` has its value changed.

Answer (score 1):

try pushing the items to a local array then setting this.ownerOptions = myArray